Command Substitution doesn't work with spaces
I'm trying to pass a list of image files to open gwenview. The only way that seems to work is to list them on command line. However, some file paths have spaces, so they have to be additionally quoted. I thought that this will work:
gwenview $(echo \"file1 with spaces.png\")
However gwenview only sees "file1" ignoring the rest of the text. I thought command substitution will faithfully replace $(echo "file1 with spaces.png") with "file1 with spaces.png" - what's going on?

Try gwenview "$(echo \"file with spaces.png\")"

You need to quote the entire command substitution: "$(echo "...")" in addition to regular quoting of whatever is inside.

Additionally this is almost certainly an XY issue.  There should be no need to pass filenames to a program with echo

@ctx thank you, I didn't expect "$()" and $() to behave differently

"However gwenview only sees "file1"" - the first argument will include the opening quote, so gwenview will see "file1 (a six character file name)

@jesse_b this is only a simplified example for illustration.
I'm trying to pass filepaths obtained from a database to gwenview.
sadly it doesn't work even with quoted process substitution.
This works: gwenview "/mnt/long path with spaces/image 1.png" "/mnt/long path with spaces/image 2.png"
but this still doesn't work gwenview "$(echo "/mnt/long path with spaces/image 1.png" "/mnt/long path with spaces/image 2.png")
my actual example performs a few more operations to process the paths, but it eventually just outputs quoted paths delimited with a space

@DanielKrajnik your solution is most likely just gwenview "$file" but you would need to ask a question about the actual problem of "how do I get from x to z" instead of "how do I get from x to y"

@jesse_b I will post it as a separate question then, I didn't think it would be necessary as it's complicated, not sure which part is causing the issue. I don't think though that gwenview "$file" would be different from gwenview "$(echo "file name1.png" "file name2.png")" if `file="$(echo "file name1.png" "file name2.png")"

@DanielKrajnik file="$(echo "file name1.png" "file name2.png")" is a useless use of command substitution and is no different than file="file name1.png file name2.png" which is almost certainly not what you want either.  Likely you want something like file=("file name1.png" "file name2.png")

@jesse_b I agree that a full explanation of the problem will help - please see my new question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/780872/gwenview-pass-file-names-from-es-exe-command-line-to-everything-voidtools I didn't mean to uselessly use process substitution
