gwenview pass file names from es.exe command line to everything voidtools
I am trying to pass filenames retrieved from everything voidtools via their es.exe command line invoked in wsl environment. Effectively, it works similarly to mlocate.
es.exe communicates with everything background process and returns paths that I'm converting with this function to WSL paths
es() {
    # Invoke the es.exe with provided arguments and pipe its output
    # through sed to replace Windows-style line endings with Unix-style line endings,
    # then use xargs to handle newline-delimited input and pass each path as a single argument to wslpath.
    # -p argument - search paths
    # -sort date-modified - sensible default
    # 2>/dev/null - remove "xargs: wslpath: terminated by signal 13"
    /mnt/c/Users/user/Downloads/ES-1.1.0.27.x64/es.exe -p -sort date-modified -instance 1.5a "$@" | sed 's/\r$//' | xargs -n1 -d'\n' wslpath 2>/dev/null
}

this for example can return all file paths that contain "plan" and "png" in their path. Results are newline delimited
es plan png
results in:
/mnt/long path with spaces/plan1.png
/mnt/long plan with spaces/path2.png
...

I'm trying then to pass it to gwenview. I couldn't pipe it, so I'm trying to pass them as command line arguments.
gwenview "$(es plan png | awk '{printf "\"%s\" ", $0}'))"

I expected it this to exand like this
gwenview "/mnt/long path with spaces/plan1.png" "/mnt/long plan with spaces/path2.png"

because writing it like this (all names copied inline) works.
However, trying to do it with process substitution doesn't work, no images are displayed. Gwenview isn't clear what error is unfortunately. My assumption is that it has to do with spaces in the paths and the way they are handled in process substitution.
Any ideas would be very appreciated.

This is a common problem people run into with trying to artificially add quotes around a string with echo and other forms of print.  You aren't actually quoting the string you are just printing a literal double quote as part of your string.  So it will expand like this:
'"/mnt/long' path with 'spaces/plan1.png"' '"/mnt/long' plan with 'spaces/path2.png"'

The quote character is not actually needed by your program you just need to escape the whitespace which is easily handled with quotes but perhaps that is leading to the confusion.
Ideally the gwenview tool would accept input from stdin although I'm not sure if it does.  In which case this would be the most logical solution:
es plan png | gwenview

However in the absence of that you probably want to use an array:
readarray -t files < <(es plan png)
gwenview "${files[@]}"

This will create the array:
files=(
'/mnt/long path with spaces/plan1.png'
'/mnt/long plan with spaces/path2.png'
)

And then pass it as:
gwenview "/mnt/long path with spaces/plan1.png" "/mnt/long plan with spaces/path2.png"


Interesting, your array example worked (yay!), but I don't understand why adding quotes around paths would be "artificial" - I thought everything in bash is plain text? Do you know by any chance what fd-find is doing to make it work? It makes it as simple as fd plan -X gweview. Man page said that it also passes files as command line arguments (that's where I got the idea from), but I've never had whitespace issue with fdfind.

Also it stops working if you try process substitution to turn it into a one-liner: gwenview $(readarray -t files < <(es plan); echo "${files[@]}") - it seems to run into whitespace issue again.

gwenview $(readarray -t files < <(es plan); echo "${files[@]}") is the same issue it's passing it all as a single unquoted string rather than individually quoted strings.  Don't obsess with one liners, they don't add any value and almost always just make things more convoluted.  Anything can be a one liner if you abuse ; enough.

right, I've tried to make it a oneliner for simplicity, the process substituted example was suggested by chatgpt (which turned out to be surprisingly inefficient solving this problem) - this works instead: readarray -t files < <(es plan); gwenview "${files[@]}"

@DanielKrajnik fair enough but that is not more simple, it's far more complicated than just letting them be their own line.

simpler in a sense that I can quickly invoke it with ctrl r, for example by "readarray" keyword, which I've not used before. But everyone has their own workflow of course.

@DanielKrajnik why not just add it all to your es function or make a new function that combines the two?

sorry @jesse_b can you please just confirm if I understand it correctly - does process substitution with echo automatically adds quotes between spaces? e.g. gwenview $(echo /mnt/path to a/file.png) results in  gwenview "/mnt/path" "to" "a/file.png"?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

the reason why I would personally (and this is just my own workflow) keep it in .bash_history instead of .bashrc is because I expect components of this command to change, for example may use feh or nsxiv instead of gwenview

This looks very much like your previous question on this same issue

@ChrisDavies.  The previous question asked how to solve the issue using command substitution, this question asked how to solve the actual problem

If it is guaranteed that no path in the output spans over multiple lines, you can do:
set -f
IFS='
'
gwenview $(es plan png)


However, given you are already using xargs, you should use it to execute whichever command you're actually interested in:
/mnt/c/Users/user/Downloads/ES-1.1.0.27.x64/es.exe -p -sort date-modified -instance 1.5a "$@" |
  sed 's/\r$//' |
  xargs -r -n1 -d'\n' sh -c 'gwenview "$(wslpath "$1")"' _ 2>/dev/null

(This calls gwenview once per path, but avoids problems with unquoted expansions. Also note the use of -r with xargs to prevent running the command if there is no input.)
Since POSIX paths can have anything in them except the ASCII NUL character \0, what you should ideally do is find a way to have es output null-delimited paths, and have xargs use null-delimited input, and then use a shell that supports arrays to allow bunching up the input per execution of gwenview:
/mnt/c/Users/user/Downloads/ES-1.1.0.27.x64/es.exe -p -sort date-modified -instance 1.5a --flag-that-results-in-\0-delimited-output "$@" |
  # GNU xargs
  xargs -r -0 bash -c '
    args=()
    for i; do
      args+=("$(wslpath "$i")")
    done;
    gwenview "${args[@]}"
  ' _ 2>/dev/null

If that is not possible, given we're on a hybrid of Windows and Linux, assuming the paths from es.exe don't have newlines in them:
/mnt/c/Users/user/Downloads/ES-1.1.0.27.x64/es.exe -p -sort date-modified -instance 1.5a "$@" |
  sed 's/\r$//' |
  xargs -r -d'\n' bash -c 'for i; do p=$(wslpath "$i"; echo x); p=${p%x}; printf "%s\0" "$p"; done' _ |
  xargs -r -0 gwenview

Here, the assumptions are only about the output of es.exe - wslpath can output any valid POSIX paths. (The x character is used here to prevent trailing newlines from being stripped by command substitution.)
If your commands are always going to be a single word, you can use a function like:
esrun () {
  cmd=$1
  shift
  /mnt/c/Users/user/Downloads/ES-1.1.0.27.x64/es.exe -p -sort date-modified -instance 1.5a "$@" |
    sed 's/\r$//' |
    xargs -r -d'\n' bash -c 'for i; do p=$(wslpath "$i"; echo x); p=${p%x}; printf "%s\0" "$p"; done' _ |
    xargs -r -0 "$cmd"
}

And use it like:
esrun gwenview plan png


thank you, could you please explain what you example sets IFS to? Is it newline? Do I understand it correctly, that this would make bash ignore whitespace altogether and thus escaping whitespace is unnecessary? Aslo, I didn't know about POSIX paths allowing everything except for null byte - thank you. Also, unfortunately, the program in question is proprietary and I may not be able to change its output format. Using xargs with individual files also won't do - I'm trying to handle the whole set in gwenview (preview thumbnails). I will try the other examples now as well.

Yes, it is setting IFS to just a newline (you can also use IFS=$'\n' on bash). This makes it ignore whitespace other than newlines while splitting the result of the command substitution, so you don't need to worry about them (but you can't escape the newline itself, if it is present)

I'm still struggling to understand my mistake, but from what I gathered so far I think that the code in bash that interprets the string that is passed by process substitution isn't the same as the code in bash that interprets string user puts on command line. Is that correct? I wonder though if it could be "fixed", that is if gwenview $(echo \"/path to a/file.png1\" \"/path to a/file.png2\") could be interpreted by bash in the same way as gwenview "/path to a/file.png1" "/path to a/file.png2"? By fixed I don't just mean setting IFS, but make bash run the same code, which it runs at cli.

Do you know by any chance where this behavior is documented? I'm struggling to "name" this and thus find good references.

If you want to make bash reinterpret something that it is the result of interpretation, you need to use eval (which is hard to use safely). Otherwise there is no way to make bash interpret quotes output as the result of command substitution (or parameter expansion). This is documented in 3.5.9 Quote Removal: "After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters ‘\’, ‘'’, and ‘"’ that did not result from one of the above expansions are removed." (emphasis added).

Put simply, there is no way to safely and easily accomplish what you want. (Also,  $(...) is command substitution, not process substitution <(...).)

thank you, eval makes more sense to me now. I can see how bash interpreting certain sequences of bytes (quotes) can behave differently in different situations. It seems unintuitive at the beginning at least, but I hope it will get easier in the future.
