Nested command substitution doesn't work, but hardcoded results work
I am trying to pass filenames retrieved from everything voidtools via their es.exe command line (it works similarly to mlocate) to an "image previewer" like gwenview or nsxiv (in wsl environemnt).
This works:
IFS=$'\n'; nsxiv $(es keyword1 keyword2)

But this doesn't work:
IFS=$'\n'; nsxiv $(es $(wl-paste))

when keyword1 keyword2 is currently stored in system clipboard.
user@wsl:~$ wl-paste | od -c
0000000   k   e   y   w   o   r   d   1       k   e   y   w   o   r   d
0000020   2  \n
0000022

Why? I thought that $() command substitution can be nested. Instead nsxiv returns No such file or directory
es is an alias that converts es.exe output to match wsl environment)
es() {
    # Invoke the es.exe with provided arguments and pipe its output
    # through sed to replace Windows-style line endings with Unix-style line endings,
    # then use xargs to handle newline-delimited input and pass each path as a single argument to wslpath.
    # -p argument - search paths
    # -sort date-modified - sensible default
    # 2>/dev/null - remove "xargs: wslpath: terminated by signal 13"
    /mnt/c/Users/user/Downloads/ES-1.1.0.27.x64/es.exe -p -sort date-modified -instance 1.5a "$@" | sed 's/\r$//' | xargs -n1 -d'\n' wslpath 2>/dev/null
}


what does wl-paste itself print in this case, exactly? e.g what does wl-paste | od -c print? If it prints keyword1<space>keyword2
, and you have IFS set to just the newline, then those two words will not be split (of course), and it's as if you ran es "keyword1 keyword2" in the shell. Anyway, in cases like this where you have multiple commands, it often helps to debug them one by one. Instead of looking at the error message the last one prints, check them all one by one.

@ilkkachu please see updated question with output from wl-paste | od -c

yep, indeed. So it should work as expected if you set IFS to the space, IFS=" " (or just leave the default value). Well, unless of course the output from es is supposed to be split only on newlines... In which case I suppose you could do something like wl-paste | tr ' ' '\n', to change the spaces to newlines. Or run the commands separately (saving the outputs to shell variables), and change IFS in between...

thank you @ilkkachu, you are right wl-paste | tr ' ' '\n' works. I chose to change IFS after issues with parsing filepaths with spaces (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/780872/gwenview-pass-file-names-from-es-exe-command-line-to-everything-voidtools) as it seemed like a simpler solution. As you can see now it bit me. If you post you comment as an answer I will accept it.

So, if wl-paste prints keyword1 keyword2, and you have IFS set to just the newline, then the shell will not split the two keywords, and es $(wl-paste) will be like running es "keyword1 keyword2" in the shell command line.
Now, assuming you want to have IFS contain only the newline for the output of es, you have some options.
Possibly simplest would be something like running nsxiv $(es $(wl-paste | tr ' ' '\n')) to change the space into a newline which would be then split on.
Or, you could do it in parts and change IFS in between:
IFS=$' \t\n'                # split on space, tab, newline (same as default)
esoutput=$(es $(wl-paste))  # the output of 'es' is not split here, yet
IFS=$'\n'                   # split on newlines only
nsxiv $esoutput

Note that in any case, the unquoted expansions will also go through globbing, so values like * or anything else that looks like a glob that happens to match an existing filename might cause issues. Add set -f to the start to disable that.

thanks, I keep getting caught off guard that plain text of shell commands is treated differently at different points of its execution, I thought it would more alike lisp where code and data are synonymous and can be arbitrarily mixed and matched

@DanielKrajnik, it's not. What you get from expansions (command substitutions like $(somecmd), or just variables like $var is more like calling a function or referring to a variable in any other programming language. E.g. var="foo()"; print(var) does not try to call the function foo() in Python either. (and quotes are similarly part of the language syntax as the function call here.) What you get from expansions is data, not code. And that's a good thing, because otherwise it would be impossible to deal with arbitrary filenames (they can contain any character, anyway).

Granted, the shell has that quaint word splitting thing, which mangles the data from expansions, but that's better thought of like a cheap and sucky substitute for proper array/list variables. And then left unused as far as possible. Zsh is smarter here that variable expansions give you the actual value by default instead of splitting, but even it splits command substitutions, blah.


"What you get from expansions is data, not code" That's what I was hoping for, but sometimes data that's returned from expansions gets interpreted differently than if it was executed from interactive command line, e.g. $(echo /mnt/path to a/file.png), becomes "/mnt/path" "to" "a/file.png" with "invisible quotes" between each space, while if executed from interactive command line it's just plain /mnt/path to a/file.png. That's why I had to change IFS. Also python, bash and lisp are all dynamically typedl, so I'm not sure why bash had to be "inconsistent" in its execution.


@DanielKrajnik, "data that's returned from expansions gets interpreted differently", yes, that's exactly the point. It's not code, it's data, so of course it's treated differently. The shell isn't a macro processor that would work on plain text replacement. The output from that command substitution is /mnt/path to a/file.png, which yes, gets word-split to the three fields /mnt/path, to,  a/file.png. If you don't want that, double-quote the expansion ("$(echo ...)").

Then again, echo might not be the best command to use for testing, since echo foo bar outputs the same as echo "foo bar". You may want to try the helper script:  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373

Thank you, these links were very helpful. Shell mechanism I seem to misunderstand is "word splitting" in relation to quoting. Namely why echo "keyword 1" "keyword 2" "keyword 3" run in "interactive shell" results in three keywords, but if run from command substitution $(echo "keyword 1" "keyword 2" "keyword 3") results in six, effectively ignoring quotations, treating them as literal characters. You said It's not code, it's data, so of course it's treated differently, but I expected the same data to be treated the same both from expansion and typed in by the user in interactive shell.

it doesn't ignore the quotes, echo "a b" "c d" "e f" passes three arguments to echo, while echo a b c d e f passes six. It's just that with echo in particular, the output is the same, because it joins the arguments it gets with spaces. Though, it's not all the fault of echo, really, because there's another point I didn't remember to point out at first: the argument list to a command is an array of distinct strings, but the output is a single "string" (byte-stream, really). So there's no simple way for echo to output the three distinct strings that were passed as arguments.

ok, the ABI for the command line args is an array of NUL-terminated strings, which themselves can't contain NULs, so the output from the program can also be a stream of NUL-terminated strings. You can get that with printf "%s\0" "a b" "c d" "e f", but Bash isn't smart enough to process that from a command substitution. You'd have to do something like readarray -d '' array < <(printf "%s\0" ...). But that gets a bit wieldy. Zsh can deal with NULs, so it might be better here, maybe. Anyway, that's what you get for backward compatibility with what they hacked up 40+ years ago...
